# How do I test if a promise was resolved or rejected using Jasmine?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, coffeescript, jasmine

I have a function that calls an API service. I want to mimic the case where the network call failed and it rejects the promise.

The method (in coffeescript):

```
find: (collection, query)
  deferred = do $q.defer
  $http.post config.server + "/api/v1/find/#{collection}", {}
  .success (result, status, headers, config) ->
    deferred.resolve result
  .error (result, status, headers, config) ->
    deferred.reject result

  deferred.promise
```

I understand how to setup a successful condition:

```
it "should make a request to the correct URL", () ->
  $httpBackend.expectPOST(server+"/api/v1/find/foo").respond(200)
  entitySvc.find "foo", {}
  do $httpBackend.flush
```

1) Should I be testing for the failure of the network call or should this be tested by the service designer, if so, how do I check if the promise was rejected?

2) The expectPOST assertion is only testing that the proper URL is being built and called from my input, but as in my previous question, I don't know that the deferred is being resolved. How can I accomplish this?